# Passing variable and value into API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

How do I pass the variable and value of current_breed into the API? I am supposed to make a GET request to dog breed website. "this.val" should contain the currently selected breed. And I need to verify that the AJAX request shows up in network tab everytime I select a breed. Here is part of the code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log("ready!");
        var imageHolder = document.getElementById("imageHolder");

        var generateButton = document.getElementById("generateButton");

        var breedsElement = document.getElementById("breeds");

        var doggieList = document.getElementById("doggieList");

        doggieList.addEventListener('change', function() {
            var current_breed = $(this).val();

            console.log(current_breed);
        });

        $.get("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", function (data) {

            console.log("Checking All Breeds Endpoint");
            console.log(data);

            var breeds = data.message;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This will all depend on your API. Does it need a GET or POST request? Does it need a Key passed along? Please take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It needs a GET request

Comment: Based ion the Docs: you just need to create the proper URL Request. See More: https://dog.ceo/dog-api/documentation/ & https://github.com/ElliottLandsborough/dog-ceo-api

Answer (score 0):

Read through the API Endpoints here for reference of the different lists you can generate:

https://github.com/ElliottLandsborough/dog-ceo-api

They all return JSON and in the following format:

```
{
  "message":""
  "status":""
}
```

If you're doing searches or seeking certain items, you might check for `"success"` or `"error"` in the status.

So in your GET request, you will need to call the `message` element of the response object.

This may be more than you're looking for yet it is also a good example.

```js
$(function() {
  var imageHolder = $("#imageHolder"),
    generateButton = $("#generateButton"),
    doggieList = $("#doggieList");

  function setBreedImg(breed) {
    console.log("Lookup Breed:", breed);
    $.getJSON("https://dog.ceo/api/breed/" + breed + "/images/random", function(j) {
      imageHolder.html("");
      console.log("Set Image", j.message);
      $("<img>", {
        src: j.message
      }).hide().appendTo(imageHolder).fadeIn();
    });
  }

  doggieList.autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      $.getJSON("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", function(j) {
        resp($.ui.autocomplete.filter(Object.keys(j.message), req.term));
      });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
      console.log("Selected", ui.item.label);
      setBreedImg(ui.item.label);
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div>
  <h3>Breeds list</h3>
  <div>
    <div class="code-wrapper breeds">
      <span class="code">https://dog.ceo/api/breed/<input type="text" id="doggieList" /></span>
    </div>
    <div id="imageHolder"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This example makes use of the jQuery UI library: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/